# Swift / URLSession: dataTask execution jumping to resume directly

Tags: swift, urlsession

trying getting a json from an API but for some reason execution does not reach 'guard let json...' instruction. Variable 'url' is being executed properly as I can see in debug mode. Execution breaks at 'URLSession.shared...' jumping to '}.resume()'

```
func retrieveDataList() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts") else { return }
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        
        guard let json = data else { return }
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            self.dataArray = try decoder.decode([List].self, from: json)
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You are missing that it using the "asynchrone" concept. So the closure will be called later.

Comment: Everything inside the scope of the closure passed to `dataTask` is executed asynchronously (in this case after `resume()` is called on the task obtained via `dataTask`).

Comment: Thanks guys. Your comments gave me a clue. I'm using a MVVM architecture and I was executing the binding (where DispatchQueue.main.async is used) in a later step. It's working now.